# How to merge json by id

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to run this code but the values ​​set in the worksheet such as e-mail, telephone are different from the fieldValues, can you help me?

it seems that the code is added to each loop and it doesn't have it complete, would I have to run a cache before setting the values ​​to the worksheet?

```
function sheetformulario() {
  var headers = {
    "Api-Token": "******",
  };
  var options = {
    method: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: headers,
  };

  i = 0;
  do {
    var url3 = "https://***.api-us1.com/api/3/contacts/?tagid=152&offset=" + i;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url3, options);
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    i += 20;

    for (x = 0; x < data.contacts.length; x++) {
      var email = data.contacts[x].email;
      var phone = data.contacts[x].phone;
      var nome = data.contacts[x].firstName + data.contacts[x].lastName;
      var id = data.contacts[x].id;

      var url4 = "https://***.api-us1.com/api/3/contacts/" + id + "/fieldValues";
      var response1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url4, options);
      var data1 = JSON.parse(response1);

      Logger.log(id);

      for (y = 0; y < data1.fieldValues.length; y++) {
        if (data1.fieldValues[y].field == "48") {
          var bronzeadora = data1.fieldValues[y].value;
        } else if (data1.fieldValues[y].field == "49") {
          var clientemedia = data1.fieldValues[y].value;
        } else if (data1.fieldValues[y].field == "55") {
          var paravoce = data1.fieldValues[y].value;
        } else if (data1.fieldValues[y].field == "56") {
          var prenda = data1.fieldValues[y].value;
        } else if (data1.fieldValues[y].field == "57") {
          var fparte = data1.fieldValues[y].value;
        } else if (data1.fieldValues[y].field == "61") {
          var difibronze = data1.fieldValues[y].value;
        } else if (data1.fieldValues[y].field == "62") {
          var tecutiliza = data1.fieldValues[y].value;
        } else if (data1.fieldValues[y].field == "66") {
          var niveldifimbg = data1.fieldValues[y].value;
        } else if (data1.fieldValues[y].field == "67") {
          var niveldifiaplicacao = data1.fieldValues[y].value;
        }

        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("****").getSheetByName("FORMACTIVE");
        var lastRow = Math.max(sheet.getLastRow(), 1);

        var val = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
        var val1 = val.some(function (row) {
          return row[0] == id;
        });

        if (!val1) {
          sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(id);
          sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2).setValue(nome);
          sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3).setValue(email);
          sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 4).setValue(phone);
          sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 5).setValue(bronzeadora);
          sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 6).setValue(tecutiliza);
          sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 7).setValue(difibronze);
          sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 8).setValue(clientemedia);
          sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 9).setValue(niveldifimbg);
          sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 10).setValue(niveldifiaplicacao);
          sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 11).setValue(paravoce);
          sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 12).setValue(prenda);
          sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 13).setValue(fparte);

          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        }
      }
    }
  } while (i <= data.meta.total);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and your image. Can I ask you about the detail of it? In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect?

Comment: Hello, sorry for my english, in the image in the part of my Name and Email: Lucas Teste and testelucas@teste.com it would have to be with those answers that I marked in red, but these answers are going to someone else "asdsa"

Comment: Can you share an example sheet and an example of the data you are getting on the script in order to test it?